# What is Clang++ required to build Blaze?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, blaze

Curious about how `Blaze`(next generation of NumPy) will be like, I tried to install with

```
pip install Blaze
```

The tarball `blaze-0.1.tar.gz` is downloaded, but error raised:

```
Clang++ is required to build Blaze.
```

**Questions**:

What is `Clang++`? I assume it is not a Python package/module. It seems to be something related to C++.

What to install to meet this requirement? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clang is a a compiler. It is required probably because blaze wants to compile some of it's files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang++ is a C++ compiler like gcc. Try `sudo apt-get install clang` to install it.

Answer (score 2):

Blaze no longer depends on Clang.

@aterrel's answer to use `conda` is still ideal if you want to install non-Python dependencies like HDF5 or BColz.

```
conda install blaze  # installs many useful packages on Mac, Linux, Windows
```

But if you don't need these (or are able to install them via other channels) then Blaze itself can be installed by pip.

```
pip install blaze --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

To install Blaze, you should try to use [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) or [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) (then `conda install blaze`), unfortunately the PyPI package is not well-maintained.  To use pip try from the development version:

`pip install git+https://github.com/ContinuumIO/blaze.git`

The requirement of Clang++ has been removed (in v0.4 I believe).

Additionally the development version is quite a bit different from that version.